# Access Symfony session values from external application

Tags: php, symfony, session-variables

I have a third party application (`responsivefilemanager` plugin for `TinyMCE`) that I can't re-write it using `Symfony2`.
I need to protect it against unauthorized users.
Is it possible to access `Symfony2`'s session variables (user, roles , etc) from external application?  **How?**
I tried to do `session_start()` and read `$_SESSION` variable, but it is empty!
My `config.yml` is:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: @ar1y4nArticleBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:         ~
    fragments:       ~

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        types: #this is about this line and line below
            json:     Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: %kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3
        # path:     %database_path%

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class:     ar1y4n\UserBundle\Entity\User

    group:
        group_class: ar1y4n\UserBundle\Entity\Group  

sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]

        #sonata.admin_doctrine_orm.block.audit:
        #    contexts:   [admin]

        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.rss:

        sonata.user.block.menu:    # used to display the menu in profile pages
        sonata.user.block.account: # used to display menu option (login option)

        # Some specific block from the SonataMediaBundle
        #sonata.media.block.media:
        #sonata.media.block.gallery:
        #sonata.media.block.feature_media:

knp_menu:
    twig:  # use "twig: false" to disable the Twig extension and the TwigRenderer
        template: knp_menu.html.twig
    templating: false # if true, enables the helper for PHP templates
    default_renderer: twig # The renderer to use, list is also available by default

sonata_user:
    security_acl: true
    class:                  # Entity Classes
        user:               ar1y4n\UserBundle\Entity\User
        group:              ar1y4n\UserBundle\Entity\Group  

sonata_admin:
    title:      My title
    title_logo: bundles/ar1y4narticle/images/logo-big.png

genemu_form:
    tinymce:
        enabled: true
        theme:   modern
        configs: {plugins: ["responsivefilemanager advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak","searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen","insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality", "emoticons template paste textcolor"],toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | responsivefilemanager",image_advtab: true, external_filemanager_path:"/filemanager/",filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}}
```

Comment: Are your sessions in memory or a data store?

Comment: @Seth: I'm using default config (`~`) for session in framework section of `config.yml` that should be memory I think. please check my edit on question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to access security context by doing this:
In `reponsivefilemanager/config/config.php` add:

```
require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '../../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once '../../app/AppKernel.php';
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
//$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel->boot();

$session = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session($kernel->getContainer()->get('session.storage'));
$session->start();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$request->setSession($session);
$event = new GetResponseEvent($kernel->getContainer()->get('http_kernel'),$request, HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST);

$firewall = $kernel->getContainer()->get('security.firewall');
$firewall->onKernelRequest($event);
if(!$kernel->getContainer()->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) die("Access Denied");
```

Of course you should change `autoload.php`, `bootstrap.php.cache` & `AppKernel.php` paths according to your file structure.
This has two problems:

- You should use `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);` when using `prod` mode (`app.php`) and `$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);` when using `dev` mode (`app_dev.php`)
- This has a problem when a non-logged in user attempts to access filemanager and gives symfony's `Access Denied` error ; however, it does the job and prevents non-granted user to use the file manager

I'm working on solving the problems; and I'll post the result here.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can read the symfony session like this :

```
// start session
session_start();

// check for symfony2 attrs first
if (isset($_SESSION['_sf2_attributes'])) {

    // check for security main information
    if (isset($_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']['_security_main'])) {

        // we are safe to go :)

        // change it , to meet your path
        require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../app/autoload.php';

       /**
        * @var Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken 
       */
        $security = unserialize($_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']['_security_main']);

        $roles = $security->getRoles();
        $user = $security->getUser();

       // do your logic here

     } else {
        die('Access Denied');
     }
  } else {
    die('Access Denied');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

in config.php before session_start(); add

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../../../../../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/../../../../../app/AppKernel.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);

$isSymfony2Authenticated = $kernel->getContainer()->get('security.context')->getToken() != null && ($kernel->getContainer()->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') || $kernel->getContainer()->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'));
if ( ! $isSymfony2Authenticated) {
    die('Access denied!');
}
```

This will check if user has ROLE_ADMIN or ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN

For Symfony 4.4

```
require dirname(__DIR__).'/../../../vendor/autoload.php';// relative path from your app
require dirname(__DIR__).'/../../../config/bootstrap.php';// relative path from your app

use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/*if ($trustedProxies = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? $_ENV['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedProxies(explode(',', $trustedProxies), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^ Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST);
}

if ($trustedHosts = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? $_ENV['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedHosts([$trustedHosts]);
}*/

$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$kernel->handle($request);
if(!$kernel->getContainer()->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) die("Access Denied");
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Symfony Session from externals:

Hello, for access from an external application to symfony session.
I hope it good, bye.

## app/config/config.yml

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/sessions"
```

### PHP Class content:

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $sesion;

/**
 * Obtiene los datos del usuario logeado en symfony
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSesion()
{
    try
    {
        if (!isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) {
            throw new \Exception("No se encontro la cookie de sesion.", 1);
        }

        $path = '\\path\\proyect';
        $archivo_sesion = $path[0].'\\app\\sessions\\sess_'.$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];

        if (!file_exists($archivo_sesion)) {
            throw new \Exception("No se encontro el archivo de sesion.", 1);                
        }

        $sesion = file_get_contents($archivo_sesion);
        $sesion = str_replace('_sf2_attributes|', '', $sesion);
        $sesion = unserialize($sesion);

        if (!isset($sesion['_security_default'])) {
            throw new \Exception("Usuario no autorizado.", 1);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        header('Location: '.$sesion['_security.default.target_path'].'login');
        die();            
    }
}
```